# Sorting and aggregating in R

Tags: r

I used the **aggregate function** in R to bring down my data entries from **90k to 1800**.

```
a=test$ID
b=test$Date
c=test$Value
d=test$Value1
sumA=aggregate(c, by=list(Date=b,Id=a), FUN=sum)
sumB=aggregate(d, by=list(Date=b,Id=a), FUN=sum)
final[1]=sumA[1],final[2]=sumA[2]
final[3]=sumA[3]/sumB[3]
```

Now I have data in **20 different dates in a month** with close to **90 different ids each day** so its around **1800 entries in the final table** .

My question is that I want to aggregate further down and find the maximum value of final[3] for each date so that I am just left with 20 values .

In simple terms - 
There are 20 days .
Each day has 90 values for 90 ids
I want to find maximum of these 90 values for each day .
So at last I would be left with just 20 values for 20 days .

Now aggregate function is not working here with function **'max'** instead of sum

```
Date    ID    Value   Value1 
1        A      20      10  
1        A      25      5  
1        B      50      5  
1        B      50      5
1        C      25      25 
1        C      35      5  
2        A      30      10  
2        A      25      45  
2        B      40      10   
2        B      40      30
```

This is the Data

Now By using Aggregate function I got final table as

```
Date    ID   x
1       A    45/15=3
1       B    100/10=10
1       c    60/30=2
2       A    55/55=1
2       B    80/40=2
```

Now I want maximum value for date 1 and 2 thats it

```
Date   max- Value
1      10
2       2
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide a small example to check the problem.

Comment: Just updated the solution with your dataset. Please check.

Comment: Can you tell me how should I use Dput in aggregate function ? I read the file via dput but it is throwing an error. Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  'data' argument is of the wrong type

Comment: You can `dput` the result.  For example `dput(res1)`.  You would be able to read the file using `read.table` or `read.csv`.  Once you read the file. e.g. `dat <- read.table("file.txt",sep="", header=T)` you could `dput(head(dat))` and see if the command works.

Comment: res1 <- aggregate(. ~daily+f, data=dput(head(text)), FUN=sum)
cannot coerce class ""noquote"" to a data.frame . Sorry for bugging  you . Correct me if you can or else I will figure it out .

Comment: `user3504466`.  Try `datH <- dput(head(test))` and then do the `aggregate(.~ daily+f, data=datH, FUN=sum)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps.

```
test <- structure(list(Date = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
Value = c(20L, 25L, 50L, 50L, 25L, 35L, 30L, 25L, 40L, 40L
), Value1 = c(10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 25L, 5L, 10L, 45L, 10L, 30L
)), .Names = c("Date", "ID", "Value", "Value1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


 res1 <- aggregate(. ~ID+Date, data=test, FUN=sum)
 res1 <- transform(res1, x=Value/Value1)
 res1
 #  ID Date Value Value1  x
 #1  A    1    45     15  3
 #2  B    1   100     10 10
 #3  C    1    60     30  2
 #4  A    2    55     55  1
 #5  B    2    80     40  2

 aggregate(. ~Date, data=res1[,-c(1,3:4)], FUN=max)
#   Date  x
# 1    1 10
# 2    2  2
```

- First I run the `aggregate` based on two grouping variables (`ID` and `Date) on the two value column by using`. ~`
- Created a new variable `x` i.e. `Value/Value1` with `transform`
- Did the final run of `aggregate` with one grouping variable (`Date`) and removed the rest of the variables except `x`.

Comment: In converting data frame to data table I see you have manually inputted the IDs which I cant because the file from which I import the data has many IDS . Is there any solution for this , like using unique function and inputting all the values ?

Comment: @user3504466.  I didn't convert data.frame to data.table in the code provided.

Comment: But the number of Ids are around 100 each file and they keep on changing , So is there any general way to adjust this ? Thanks man for replying so quick.

Comment: @user3504466. Sorry, I didn't understand your question.  Adjust to what?

Comment: Sorry but I mean how should I make the structure manually when I have so many ids which keep on changing . A,b,c are just to show you , there are around 100 of them and may be more

Comment: @user3504466. You can create it by just `dput(data)`. This was done for easy reproducibility and testing the code.  If there are 100s of them, the output will be really big.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one step process using data table. The data.table is an evolved version of data.frame, and works really well. It has the class of data.frame, so works just like data.frame.

Step0: Converting data.frame to data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)
setkey(test,Date,ID)
```

Step1: Do the computation

```
test[,sum(Value)/sum(Value1),by=key(test)][,max(V1),by=Date]
```

Here the explanation of the step:
The first part creates what you call the final table in your question:

```
test[,sum(Value)/sum(Value1),by=key(test)]
#    Date ID V1
# 1:    1  A  3
# 2:    1  B 10
# 3:    1  C  2
# 4:    2  A  1
# 5:    2  B  2
```

Now this is passed to the second item to do the max function by Date:

```
test[,sum(Value)/sum(Value1),by=key(test)][,max(V1),by=Date]
#    Date V1
# 1:    1 10
# 2:    2  2
```

Hope this helps.
It's a very well documented package. You should read more about it.

Comment: In converting data frame to data table I see you have manually inputted the IDs which I cant because the file from which I import the data has many IDS . Is there any solution for this , like using unique function and inputting all the values ?

Comment: You don't have to put all the IDs. Only those ones you want to group by.

Comment: But the number of Ids are around 100 each file and they keep on changing , So is there any general way to adjust this ? Thanks man for replying so quick.

Comment: I dont think it will matter how many IDs are there. Have you tried the code above?

Comment: Just a note: You don't need to `setkey` to aggregate. *ad-hoc* by is much faster, and retains the input order. If necessary, setting key or ordering can be done after the aggregation, as the data'll be smaller.